# Add date from JXDatePicker into SQL Database in Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, datepicker

I would like to add a date value from JXDatePicker into my SQL database, however I'm getting this error when running it:

java.sql.sqldataexception: the syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect

This is my code:

```
try {
    String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Members";
    String username = "admin1";
    String password = "admin1";

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    String query = "INSERT INTO BOOKING(MEMBERID, NAME, CONTACT, "
            + "EMAILADDRESS, RESERVATIONDATE, RESERVATIONTIME) "
            + "VALUES('"+txtMemberID.getText()+"', '"+txtName.getText()+"', "
            + "'"+txtContact.getText()+"', '"+txtEmail.getText()+"', "
            + "'"+comboDate.getDate()+"', '"+comboTime.getSelectedItem()+"')";

    stmt.execute(query);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Booking created");

    txtMemberID.setText(null);
    txtName.setText(null);
    txtContact.setText(null);
    txtEmail.setText(null);
    comboDate.setDate(null);
    comboTime.setSelectedItem("00");

    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
    }
```

The datatype specified for the Date attribute in my database is Date.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share the table description for `BOOKING` (including data types of columns? You need to use a `PreparedStatement` for executing the `INSERT`.

Comment: `create table "ADMIN1".BOOKING
(
 MEMBERID VARCHAR(6) not null primary key,
 NAME LONG VARCHAR not null,
 CONTACT VARCHAR(9) not null,
 EMAILADDRESS LONG VARCHAR not null,
 RESERVATIONDATE DATE not null,
 RESERVATIONTIME VARCHAR(6) not null
)`

May I ask how does the `PreparedStatement` work? I've tried various codes I found while searching online but there's always errors appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to embed a `Date` value (or a `String` representation of one) into the `INSERT` statement. Instead of concatenating variables into the query literal, you should use  *parameterized SQL* through a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). In addition to protecting your code from [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), parameterized statements are re-usable by the database, which means that the DB doesn't need to parse the SQL before each execution -- this is especially important if you're running a large number of queries in a loop.

Another thing that you should take care of, is closing the resources you've opened. In your example code, the `Connection` and `Statement` are left open after they are no longer needed. This is easy to fix using the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which was introduced in Java 7. The resources declared within the `try` clause get automatically closed after the statement is executed.

Putting it all together, here's an example of what the modified code could look like:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO BOOKING(MEMBERID, NAME, CONTACT, "
        + "EMAILADDRESS, RESERVATIONDATE, RESERVATIONTIME) "
        + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
     PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query)) {

    ps.setString(1, txtMemberID.getText());
    ps.setString(2, txtName.getText());
    ps.setString(3, txtContact.getText());
    ps.setString(4, txtEmail.getText());
    ps.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(comboDate.getDate().getTime()));
    ps.setString(6, comboTime.getSelectedItem().toString());

    ps.executeUpdate();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Booking created");

    /*clear the UI components etc.*/

} catch(SQLException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I'm still facing this error for my Date: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date. Is there a way to convert it properly, and where should the code be placed?

Comment: Sorry, my bad; I edited the answer to fix the date-handling.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you soooo much!! This really helped a lot! :)